# @Autowired BeanCreationException with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, autowired

I know this question has been asked many times but I've been stuck on this for a few days and cannot figure out why this is happening.

Here is my JUnit test suite, and **the issue happens when I try to @Autowire RequestService**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/*.xml"})
public class RequestServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private RequestService requestService;

    @Test
    public void add() throws Exception {
        requestService.add(new Request(1, "hello"));
        requestService.add(new Request(2, "hi"));
        Request requestResponseFromDatabase = (Request) requestService.findById(1);
        assertEquals("hello", requestResponseFromDatabase.getRestRequestParameters());
    }
}
```

---

Below is my code for my model, DAO, and service classes.

Model (leaving out the constructor and other fields for brevity)

```
@Entity
public class Request implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer restRequestId;

    private Timestamp restRequestTimestamp;

    private String restRequestParameters;
}
```

---

DAO

```
@Component
public class RequestDAO {

    @Autowired
    private RequestService requestService;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void persist(Request request) {
        entityManager.persist(request);
    }

    public void update(Request request) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(request);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public Object findById(Serializable id) {
        Request request = entityManager.find(Request.class, id);
        if (request == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Cannot find Request for ID " + id);
        }
        return request;
    }

    public void delete(Request request) {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.remove(request);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void deleteById(Serializable id) {
        Request request = entityManager.find(Request.class, id);
        if (request == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Cannot find Request for ID " + id);
        } else if (request != null) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.remove(request);
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }

    public List<Request> findAll() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e from Request e");
        List<Request> requests = query.getResultList();
        return requests;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        List<Request> requests = findAll();
        for (Request request : requests) {
            delete(request);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Service

```
@Component
public class RequestService {

    @Autowired
    private RequestDAO requestDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void add(Request request) {
        requestDAO.persist(request);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Request request) {
        requestDAO.update(request);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Object findById(Serializable id) {
        return requestDAO.findById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(Request request) {
        requestDAO.delete(request);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(Request request) {
        requestDAO.delete(request);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteAll() {
        requestDAO.deleteAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addAll(Collection<Request> requestCollection) {
        for (Request request : requestCollection) {
            requestDAO.persist(request);
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Request> findAll() {
        return requestDAO.findAll();
    }
}
```

---

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        ">


<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.mypackage"/>

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem://requestDb"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="pass"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:packagesToScan="com.company.mypackage"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManger" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManger"/>


</beans>
```

---

Full stacktrace:

```
May 23, 2016 1:57:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
May 23, 2016 1:57:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper instantiateListeners
INFO: Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
May 23, 2016 1:57:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@3498ed, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a407d53, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@3d8c7aca, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@5ebec15, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@21bcffb5]
May 23, 2016 1:57:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@548b7f67: startup date [Mon May 23 13:57:38 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
May 23, 2016 1:57:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a407d53] to prepare test instance [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest@57175e74]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest.requestService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest.requestService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 32 more


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest.requestService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest.requestService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 32 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

---

Additional Details

- Spring version: 4.2.5.RELEASE
- Hibernate version: 5.1.0.Final
- My spring.xml is located within src/main/resources (yes I am aware that it is not the best practice but wanted to make sure my tests work first. I did try to keep it in my src/test/resources folder but kept getting issues with my ApplicationContext not being able to load)

Resources followed:

- [@Autowired with JUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462926/autowired-with-junit-tests)
- [@AUTOWIRED : BeanCreationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821085/autowired-beancreationexception)
- [@Autowired fails with JUnit & Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101715/autowired-fails-with-junit-spring)
- [Spring not autowiring in unit tests with JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623694/spring-not-autowiring-in-unit-tests-with-junit)
- [Spring ORM example with JPA, Hibernate, Transactions](http://www.journaldev.com/7655/spring-orm-example-with-jpa-hibernate-transactions)

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I have asked similar questions to this in the past and do apologize - having a hard time understanding Spring along with all of it's documentation. I want to make sure I fully understand this to avoid making the same mistake in the future.

---

**EDIT:** Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Stack trace when using `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring.xml"})`:

```
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper instantiateListeners
INFO: Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@60f82f98, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@35f983a6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@7f690630, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@edf4efb, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@2f7a2457]
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@174d20a: startup date [Mon May 23 15:20:39 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 23, 2016 3:20:39 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
May 23, 2016 3:20:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : User not found: USER
May 23, 2016 3:20:40 PM org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
May 23, 2016 3:20:40 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@35f983a6] to prepare test instance [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestServiceTest@481ba2cf]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set



Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: where is your spring.xml is located?

Comment: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.mypackage.request.service.RequestService] found`

Comment: @Jens src/main/resources. I know it should be in my src/test/resources but my test suite was not able to read it.

Comment: Change `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/*.xml"})` to `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/*.xml"})`

Comment: @Jens that gives me the same error. :(

Comment: Is the package name com.company.mypackage right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error msg is very clear, you need to config your hibernate properly.

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

The possible reason could be:

1. You haven't setup your hibernate properly.
2. or there is no DB running during the test

Answer (score 1):

The problem happening over here is it is not able to load your `spring bean xml` file. can you put your `spring xml` file directly at the root level in the `classpath`.

Comment: Hi shankarsh15, thank you for your reply. I tried to do this, however I still receive the same error.

Comment: change @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring.xml"})

Comment: Tried that, still did not work. I added my folder structure to help. I moved my spring.xml file back to my resources folder.

Comment: Ideally files under src/main/resources come directly under the classpath(root level). Now try @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring.xml"})  keeping spring.xml under src/main/resources only.

Comment: Changed it, now I receive a 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext'. Editing my post to add the full stack trace of that.

Comment: Now its different issue meaning its able to read your spring.xml .Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set.  check if your database is up otherwise you can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create"